# How do I get a listing of only files using Dir.glob?

Tags: ruby

How can I return a list of only the files, not directories, in a specified directory?

I have `my_list = Dir.glob(script_path.join("*"))`

This returns everything in the directory,including subdirectories. I searched but haven't been able to find the answer.

Answer (score 31):

In addition to Mark's answer, `Dir.entries` will give back directories. If you just want the files, you can test each entry to see if it's a file or a directory, by using `file?`.

```
Dir.entries('/home/theiv').select { |f| File.file?(f) }
```

Replace `/home/theiv` with whatever directory you want to look for files in.

Also, have a look at [File](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/File.html). It provides a bunch of tests and properties you can retrieve about files.

Comment: I had to use `File.file?("/home/theiv/#{f}")`

Comment: in the mapping section: select {|f| File.file?(f)}, the |f| is just the file name, not complete path. So you need to compose a complete one, say File.file?("/home/theiv/#{f}"), otherwise it doesn't work. Or for a simpler way, use: !File.directory(f) instead.

Answer (score 14):

`Dir.glob('*').select { |fn| File.file?(fn) }`

Answer (score 8):

Entries don't do rescursion i think. If you want the files in the subdirs also use

```
puts Dir['**/*'].select { |f| File.file?(f) }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it in one go instead of first creating an array and then iterating over it with `select`, you can do something like:

```
my_list = []
Dir.foreach(dir) { |f| my_list << f if File.file?(f) }
```

Answer (score 3):

Following @karl-li 's suggestion in @theIV solution, I found this to work well:

```
Dir.entries('path/to/files/folder').reject { |f| File.directory?(f) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Dir[]`/`Dir.glob` or `Dir.entries` to get file listing. The difference between them is the former returns complete path, and the latter returns only filename.

So be careful about the following mapping segment `.select {|f| File.file?(f)}`: with complete path it works well, while with only filename, it sometimes works wired.

FYR:

[Dir[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D), [Dir.glob](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob), [Dir.entries](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-entries)

Answer (score 0):

you can basically just get filenames with `File.basename(file)`

```
Dir.glob(script_path.join("*")).map{ |s| File.basename(s) }
```

Answer (score -4):

It sounds like you're looking for [`Dir.entries`](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Dir.html#M000846):

> Returns an array containing all of the filenames in the given directory. Will raise a SystemCallError if the named directory doesn’t exist.

If searching Google for how to solve this problem isn't turning up any results, you can look through the Ruby documentation.

Comment: `Dir.entries` returns both files and subdirectories, and is similar to `glob` without the filename mask. `  Dir.entries("testdir")   #=> [".", "..", "config.h", "main.rb"]`. The first two values returned are directories.