# Get files recursively inside directory in ruby

Tags: ruby

Given the following directory structure:

```
$  tree .
.
└── some
    ├── Rakefile
    └── path
        ├── bar.erb
        └── to
            └── baz.rb

3 directories, 3 files
```

I'm able to get all files (including directories), only directories, and only files:

```
p Dir.glob('some/**/*')
#=> ["some/Rakefile", "some/path", "some/path/bar.erb", "some/path/to", "some/path/to/baz.rb"]
p Dir.glob('some/**/*/')
#=> ["some/path/", "some/path/to/"]
p Dir.glob('some/**/*').select { |f| File.file? f }
#=> ["some/Rakefile", "some/path/bar.erb", "some/path/to/baz.rb"]
```

Is there a more terse way to get only the files and not dirs (the third case)?

Edit:

Just to add an explicit answer to my question:
No. there isn't a shorter way, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677410/how-do-i-get-a-listing-of-only-files-using-dir-glob)

Comment: Actually given your structure all you need to do is add a check for the extension e.g. `Dir.glob("some/**/*.*")` since your directories do not include a dot this will do as asked. Also given that all your files end in `rb` then `Dir.glob("some/**/*.*rb")` will also work for you. This will neglect extentionless files but that does not seem to be a problem for you

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky! The problem is I'd like to include files like `Rakefile`. I added an edit.

Comment: Ahh something beyond the question asked. Well yes in that case you have the correct answer.